# Cannot find fixes to apt error: Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, hash, apt

I have not been able to install any package, or even use `apt update`!
I am running Kubuntu 20.04.
Output is shown below for various commands:

```bash
$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
...
Get:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release.gpg [836 B]                              
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]                             
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages  
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:970408 [weak]
   - SHA256:7757921ff8feed9c3934a0c9936d441ba4a238bee3ea6c8c1df5cbcd43fc9861
   - SHA1:2636185704086dc5ae66ad1d0c51a8c7a9cb81eb [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9979260eea32514325bcd05e9e651368 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:a3bbbfe89a5bd3fce141661567339a53a0fdaab86e23b74dd3e67fd886a0c7c3
   - SHA1:da15d0a26ca8f594d3e8c25bb5a878643da3b9a0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:19b476a5c162982e2bb987c5df831b66 [weak]
   - Filesize:970408 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 16:40:26 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]
...
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [636 kB]                                               
Err:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                                          
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:635528 [weak]
   - SHA256:70c6a88ecf724ac568f264d9c975068fa61c283d0e2279966881d5cd2af09aba
   - SHA1:72d9d1d9e9423db406f08315d80154c6d2cbf40c [weak]
   - MD5Sum:25ad47ac9cbd0f818597cf6be854e049 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:295c3504682fd33be49c5afcdb40d225b1d7b6c75c81fcbc923787eb1b051b8d
   - SHA1:75e130cef2956049077fe87b7c85986d16fe25d0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2f47cfef626fb3b6c44591046f2f9e25 [weak]
   - Filesize:635528 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 22:04:51 +0000
  Release file created at: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 23:33:05 +0000
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [325 kB]   
...
Get:68 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [700 kB]
Err:68 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages          
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:699968 [weak]
   - SHA256:b5232dbec6fbaf9c5c46e510c6e18986d843158be8d7acb9dabf1a2fcbbc3e96
   - SHA1:ee8603d304383bf96bae4d81b697edde3edf7c68 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:be9c383e4e7017ee36cd1e7603cdf9ab [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:b80f903ea4fc3000fba4d7a5084f949f94d2d7f1bd7f2bf654b849f0d84633ed
   - SHA1:eedea703d9dc9503b4ce88854a8ad5ba9b8e53b5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:45f08ab3a180c655e46606a8189cc5c8 [weak]
   - Filesize:699968 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 14:46:34 +0000
  Release file created at: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 23:32:16 +0000
Get:69 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [550 kB]  
...
Fetched 14.5 MB in 2s (7,574 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/7757921ff8feed9c3934a0c9936d441ba4a238bee3ea6c8c1df5cbcd43fc9861  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:970408 [weak]
    - SHA256:7757921ff8feed9c3934a0c9936d441ba4a238bee3ea6c8c1df5cbcd43fc9861
    - SHA1:2636185704086dc5ae66ad1d0c51a8c7a9cb81eb [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9979260eea32514325bcd05e9e651368 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:a3bbbfe89a5bd3fce141661567339a53a0fdaab86e23b74dd3e67fd886a0c7c3
    - SHA1:da15d0a26ca8f594d3e8c25bb5a878643da3b9a0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:19b476a5c162982e2bb987c5df831b66 [weak]
    - Filesize:970408 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 16:40:26 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/9f4ffba2a05dc2fb76857d4b30ed55724fe6e2999341694f2b86940ab067a44b  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/70c6a88ecf724ac568f264d9c975068fa61c283d0e2279966881d5cd2af09aba  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:635528 [weak]
    - SHA256:70c6a88ecf724ac568f264d9c975068fa61c283d0e2279966881d5cd2af09aba
    - SHA1:72d9d1d9e9423db406f08315d80154c6d2cbf40c [weak]
... (The list continues)
   Last modification reported: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 14:46:34 +0000
   Release file created at: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 23:32:16 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


$ sudo apt install snapd

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate
```

Just to make this clear, I have used methods such as:

- `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
- `sudo apt update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz`
- `sudo apt clean`
- modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Nowhere on the internet have I been able to find any fix to this problem. Other methods, such as the GUI package manager also fail with the same error.
Please help!

EDIT:
I used a wifi dongle instead of ethernet, and the problem just somehow disappeared! When I switch back, however, apt will throw the error again.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I replaced my router system and it's now all good.